# What process(s) writes to ALERT log file in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Team:

I have been searching for the process(s) which write to alert log file but couldn't find any reference to the documentation. I believe the background processes write to alert log. Not sure if it's correct. Also, does a server process write to alert log as well? We see a lot of entries in the alert log which states some info is written to trace file abc.trc etc, I was wondering if the particular background process involved with that error write inti that particular trace file.

Comment: In general I believe it is background processes like pmon and/or smon that write to the alert log. If you're on Linux you can use a command like lsof to confirm that. That said, why does it matter?

Comment: Hi @pmdba
Thanks for the reply. I got curious because of this line in alert log:
`Instance shutdown complete`
So if a background process was indeed writing to alert log file, once the db is shutdown, all the bg processes whould have disappeared. was wondering who wrote that line to alert log.

Comment: should be smon or pmon. probably the last thing they do on the way out the door... not sure why it matters.

Comment: It doesn't always have to matter :) It's just curiosity. Coz we are working as DBAs so it's good to know how it was designed to function. Thanks for the reply again.

Answer (score 1):

Any process can write in the alert log.

Even you can write in the alert log using the PL/SQL `DBMS_SYSTEM` package.

Trace file names clearly indicate which process they belong to. Trace files are named like `ORCL_smon_1234.trc`, where `ORCL` is the name of the instance, `smon` is the name of the server process, `1234` is the OS PID of the process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Balazs